# Turning Plotly object into a Numpy array fast

Tags: python, numpy, plotly

I have the below code I am running

```
        img_bytes = fig.to_image(format="png", width=2240, height=2240, scale=2)
        img = PILImage.create(BytesIO(img_bytes))
        img = img.resize((224, 224))
```

The problem is it is taking 3.5 seconds for the first line to run. I need to make this significantly faster. I can't use width/height parameters as 224 because it makes the labels massive relative to the graph. But I need to end up with an image that is 224x224.

Does anyone know a faster way of doing this? Needs to be 10x faster really.

I've tried nothing else so far. All my searching has taken me to BytesIO to keep the image in memory but it's still too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!
You carefully render five million pixels,
and then discard 99% of them.

I cannot run your code.
But I can read the
[docs](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.to_image.html).

```
        img_bytes = fig.to_image(... , scale=2)
```

The documentation explains that in your current code

> A scale factor larger than 1.0 will increase the image resolution with respect to the figure’s layout pixel dimensions.

whereas

> a scale factor of less than 1.0 will decrease the image resolution

which is exactly what you do in the subsequent source line.

Adjust `scale` so text fonts come out properly for a smaller image size.
Don't ask for millions of pixels that you'll just discard a moment later.

Comment: Yes you're right of course. I changed scale to 0.1 and it sped it up. I still have to do the img.resize to get the code to work but it's near instantaneuos.